# Parse func f(arg1, arg2: type) in lex yacc compiler

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, yacc

I successfully parse:

```
func f(a: int) return int{}
```

And

```
func f(a: int; b: string) return int{}
```

But I fail to parse

```
func f(a, c: int; b: string) return int{}
```

My compiler fails to catch whatever comes behind the comma and I cant figure out how to fix it.
What I get in the third case is c as an int, b as a string and null as an a (as opposed to a as an int).

The rules I use-

```
function:
FUNC iden_name O_PAREN parameters C_PAREN RETURN ident_type block { 
    Node * left = makeTripNode("FUNCTION", $7, $2, $4 );
    Node * right = $8;
    $$ = makePairNode("FUNCTION", left, right ); 
}
parameters:
parameters SEMICOLON parameter { $$ = makePairNode("PARAMETERS", $1, $3); }
    | parameters COMMA parameter { $$ = makePairNode("PARAMETERS", $1, $3); }
    | parameter {$$ = $1;}
    ;
parameter:
iden_name COLON ident_type { $$ = makePairNode("PARAM", $3, $1); }
    | iden_name {$$ = $1;}
    ;
```

Answer (score 3):

The rule

```
parameters:
parameters SEMICOLON parameter { $$ = makePairNode("PARAMETERS", $1, $3); }
    | parameters COMMA parameter { $$ = makePairNode("PARAMETERS", $1, $3); }
    | parameter {$$ = $1;}
    ;
```

defines that `parameters` is a sequence of something called `parameter`, separated by either a semicolon or a comma. Right away it doesn't look like what you are after, since it will accept `a: int, b: string`.

Meanwhile, according to the next rule it is OK to have a parameter consisting go just an `ident_name`. This is exactly how `a,` is treated: a typeless `a` separated from the rest by a comma.

If I understand your intentions correctly, consider something along the lines of

```
parameters
    : parameters SEMICOLON typed_parameter group
    | typed_parameter_group
    ;

typed_parameter_group
    : parameter_list COLON ident_type
    | parameter_list
    ;

parameter_list
    : parameter_list COMMA iden_name
    | iden_name
    ;
```

Comment: I tried something like this-
`parameters: parameters SEMICOLON typed_parameter_group { $$ = makePairNode("PARAMETERS", $1, $3); }
    | typed_parameter_group {$$ = $1;}
    ;

typed_parameter_group: parameter_list COLON ident_type { $$ = makePairNode("PARAM", $3, $1); }
    | parameter_list {$$ = $1;}
    ;

parameter_list: parameter_list COMMA iden_name {$$ = $1;}
    | iden_name {$$ = $1;}
    ;
`
And now when parsing, I seem to successfully parse a and b, but not c in this case-
`func f(a, c: int; b: string) return int{}
`
or at least I cant find c in my AST.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider what yacc will see when parsing `a, c: int`, you have

```
iden_name COMMA iden_name COLON ident_type
```

Therefore, since the comma clause specifies a list of parameter names, it should be part of `parameter` rule and not part of `parameters`.  `parameter` will need to be updated to support a list of `iden_name`s.

Comment: How would you do it?
I've tried, for example, 
`iden_name COMMA parameter { $$ = makePairNode("PARAMETERS", $1, $3); }`
under parameter rule, but I still get c->int, b->string, null->a